# My code returns None instead of returning the count value when I use Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm a complete beginner to programming and I have recently completed a course on Intro to Python so I set out to practice my fundamentals on CodeWars. I wanted to use Recursion in the below problem but it kept returning None instead of the count. I want to know whats the error.

> In a small town the population is p0 = 1000 at the beginning of a
> year. The population regularly increases by 2 percent per year and
> moreover 50 new inhabitants per year come to live in the town. How
> many years does the town need to see its population greater or equal
> to p = 1200 inhabitants?

My code is:

```
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p):
    global count
    if p0 >= p:
        return count 
    p0 = p0 + (p0*(percent/100))+aug
    count = count + 1
    nb_year(p0,percent,aug,p)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `return nb_year(p0,percent,aug,p)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return in the Recursive case.

```
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p):
    global count
    if p0 >= p:
        return count 
    p0 = p0 + (p0*(percent/100))+aug
    count = count + 1
    return nb_year(p0,percent,aug,p)
```

Comment: It looks like you have put your question in the title.  Please include your question in the text of your post.

Answer (score 0):

You actually didn't return anything. Therefore it prints `none`.
To avoid that you can add a return statement to your code.

```py
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p):
    global count
    if p0 >= p:
        return count 
    p0 = p0 + (p0*(percent/100))+aug
    count = count + 1
    return nb_year(p0,percent,aug,p) #this where you have to add the return statement
```